# Is there a way to convert c# class to JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have C# class which I need to convert to Json file, and I tried looking for some online tools to do that but could not find

Can someone know if we can change it to Json string online or not?

Sample c# class:

```
public enum Culture
    {
        GB,
        US,
        IT,
        FR,
        CA,
        DE,
        SE,
        NL,
        NZ,
        AU,
        AE,
        CN,
        JP,
        IE,
        IN,
        ES
    }
    public class FullName
    {
        public string First;
        public string Last;
        public FullName(string first, string last)
        {
            this.First = first;
            this.Last = last;
        }
    }
    public class StringResourcesX
    {

        public static string HTMLAttribute_QA { get; set; }

        public static string DOB { get; set; }
    public static Dictionary<Culture, FullName> CulturalNames = new Dictionary<Culture, FullName>
    {
        {Culture.GB, new FullName(GB_Name, GB_LastName)},{Culture.US, new FullName(US_Name , US_LastName)},
        {Culture.IT, new FullName(IT_Name, IT_LastName)},{Culture.ES, new FullName(ES_Name, ES_LastName)},
        {Culture.FR, new FullName(FR_Name, FR_LastName)},{Culture.AE, new FullName(AE_Name, AE_LastName)},
        {Culture.DE, new FullName(DE_Name, DE_LastName)},{Culture.NL, new FullName(NL_Name, NL_LastName)},
        {Culture.JP, new FullName(JP_Name, JP_LastName)},{Culture.SE, new FullName(SE_Name, SE_LastName)},
        {Culture.IE, new FullName(IE_Name, IE_LastName)},{Culture.AU, new FullName(AU_Name, AU_LastName)},
        {Culture.CA, new FullName(CA_Name, CA_LastName)},{Culture.NZ, new FullName(NZ_Name, NZ_LastName)},
        {Culture.IN, new FullName(IN_Name, IN_LastName)},{Culture.CN, new FullName(CN_Name, CN_LastName)}
    };
}
```

I have really long file which I need to convert to Json string, so wanted to know rather doing it manually, if we have any online tool where we can use?

Comment: Your sample "class", is two classes and an enum. Can you provide an example of what you would expect the json string to look like for this sample, especially for the method `FullName(...)`?

Comment: Hi, in my second class I'm using the full name, please see class "StringResourcesX"

Comment: It sounded like you were wanting to serialize a C# class definition, but I am guessing you just want to store some objects (i.e. instances of your classes), in which case Paddy's answer is a good place to start.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Got a link with that?

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using NewtonSoft's JsonConvert.SerializeObject method:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm

For example:

```
var instance = new FullName {
    First="Bob",
    Last="DaBuilda"
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this now

Answer (score 0):

you can try out this link : https://csharp2json.io/

and before you try to convert JSON assign the value of all class member.
this example is already given by on this web